# c# rules editor, advice or suggestions

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, architecture

I want to provide predefined filters for displaying search results. The filter is more or less stored as an expression tree and can be constructed using a rule editor.

I want to provide the user with an editor, select a property, select the operator and allow the user to provide or select a value to compare with.

[dropdown with properties = PriorityId] [dropdown with operators = Equals] [dropdown with values = IList()]

The challenge is that the user needs to get a list of values to select from and I am figuring out how to

I have thought about the following approach, and I would like to get your input on this.

- Decorate the property with an attribute
- The attribute maps a class responsible for returning possible values
- The mapping class implements an interface

When selecting the property from the rule editor I can execute an ajax call to a supporting controller to get the values back. In this controller I can invoke the mapping class via reflection to return the values.

```
namespace Tickets.Data.Model
{
    public class Ticket : BaseModel
    {
        [RuleEditorCollectionMapping(typeof(GetPriorities))]
        public string PriorityId { get; set; }
    }
}


public class RuleEditorCollectionMappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Type classType;
    public RuleEditorCollectionMappingAttribute(Type classType)
    {
        this.classType = classType;
    }
}

public interface IRuleEditorCollectionMapping{}
public class GetPriorities : IRuleEditorCollectionMapping
{
    public static IList<TicketPriority> GetValues()
    {
    // query logic to build a list with values to be used in the rules editor when selecting PriorityId
        return new List<TicketPriority>();
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Is my approach a viable one? More or less a sanity check so I don't take the wrong turn.
- If not, do you have any other suggestions or guidance from experience to approach this situation?

Comment: But what is your question? Be aware that Stack Overflow is not a chat forum or a discussion website.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, I'll admit it is more of a discussion for the best way to approach this situation. I hope this isn't an issue.